# How can a Firebase Hosting deployed website find out what version it is?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

When deploying websites to Firebase Hosting, each deployment is given a version. In the Firebase Hosting UI you can view previously deployed versions and rollback to them.

Is there a way for the deployed frontend to know which deployed version it is?